# Reduce $\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}} - \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}$ and get it down to size ( simplest form)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Reduce this radical down to size .
>   $$\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}} - \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}$$

I have the 'trick' but was looking to confirm it, so posting it on here for some of greatest mathematicians to take a look at.

Comment: Did you forget to include the radical?

Comment: Yes sir ..and just added it lol

Comment: If you have a "trick", then you really should show it (either as part of the question, or as your own answer). Getting people to tell you (or guess-at) stuff you already know isn't really the best use of this site.

Comment: Yes sir ..was attempting to see if the same trick was used by anyone else

Comment: The trick was to call the ' ugly radical ' N , then square both sides and it will fall apart and reduce down ! I see below other mathletes did it too

Answer (score 6):

Squaring gives $2\times \frac 34-2\times \sqrt{\frac 9{16}-\frac 12}$  This in turn is $\frac 32 -2\times \frac 14=1$.  As the number is negative it must be $\fbox {-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\frac{3}{4}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{3}{4}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{4}}=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\frac{3-2\sqrt{2}}{4}=\frac{(\sqrt{2}-1)^2}{4}$$

Same way
$$\frac{3}{4}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{(\sqrt{2}+1)^2}{4}$$

From here it is easy...

Answer (score 1):

This immediately becomes 
$$
\frac12\sqrt{3-2\sqrt{2}} - \frac12\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{2}}
$$

Note that $$(1\pm\sqrt{2})^2 = 3 \pm \sqrt{2}$$

Using that for the square roots the $\sqrt{2}$ terms cancel and you get the answer $-1$.